# sceneKit physics body's scale doesn't adhere attached node

Tags: ios, scenekit

In my situation, I need update physics body's scale when attached node's scale changed. However, physics body of node always be identity after node's scale changed. After print node's scale, I'm sure it contain new value.

My code is here, it is sample and not work. when I shrink collisionMesh, physics body still remain size of identity scale.

```
SCNNode *collisionMesh = childNode;
collisionMesh.scale = self.selectedRsc.scale;
NSLog(@"selectedRsc:%@",aimNode);
NSLog(@" selectedRsc scal:%@",[NSValue valueWithSCNVector3: aimNode.scale]);
NSLog(@" collisionMesh scal:%@",[NSValue valueWithSCNVector3: collisionMesh.scale]);
SCNPhysicsBody *body = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeKinematic shape:[SCNPhysicsShape shapeWithGeometry:collisionMesh.geometry options:nil]];
body.categoryBitMask =bitmaskCollision;
collisionMesh.physicsBody = body;
```

Answer (score 4):

With some effort of searching in the internet, I found physics engine typically doesn't support scale transforms.There are some [informations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893083/scenekit-wont-scale-a-dynamic-body).

I also found that pass nil to shape parameter of +bodyWithType:shape: will work fine.

```
SCNNode *collisionMesh = childNode;
collisionMesh.scale = self.selectedRsc.scale;
NSLog(@"selectedRsc:%@",aimNode);
NSLog(@" selectedRsc scal:%@",[NSValue valueWithSCNVector3: aimNode.scale]);
NSLog(@" collisionMesh scal:%@",[NSValue valueWithSCNVector3: collisionMesh.scale]);
//this will work fine, physics body will get correct scale.
SCNPhysicsBody *body = [SCNPhysicsBody bodyWithType:SCNPhysicsBodyTypeKinematic shape:nil];
body.categoryBitMask =bitmaskCollision;
collisionMesh.physicsBody = body;
```

So I made further digging in apple's docs and noted this description.
 According to [SCNPhysicsShapeScaleKey reference](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsshapescalekey)

> SceneKit’s physics simulation ignores the 
>   scale
>    property of nodes containing physics bodies when simulating collisions. Instead, use this option to provide a scale factor when creating custom physics shapes. (If you create a physics body for a node without specifying a custom shape, SceneKit uses the node’s scale property to infer this scale factor at creation time.)

This explain why pass nil will work. When create a physics body of node without specifying a shape, sceneKit automatically calculate shape base on attached node's geometry which will take node's scale transform into consideration.

Also you can specify scale factor by using the option of  `SCNPhysicsShapeScaleKey`.